# .htaccess rewrite PHP $_GET multiple pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule register index.php?mode=register
    RewriteRule login index.php?mode=login
```

index.php

```php
    <?php
    if ( isset ( $_GET['mode']) && ( $_GET['mode'] == 'register' ) ) {
        include('includes/register.php');
    } elseif ( isset ( $_GET['mode']) && ( $_GET['mode'] == 'login' ) ) {
        include('includes/login.php');  
    }
    ?>
```

This is my current method (thanks to @TROODON).

Is there an easier way, maybe using key-value arrays to store all the possibilities for the various pages that index.php will call?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `.htaccess` you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, don't change your PHP code to just `include` whatever you are getting from `$_GET['mode']`! This will allow users to include at will.

You could adjust your PHP code like so:

```
$pages = array("register" => "includes/register.php",
               "login"    => "includes/login.php");

if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $pages[$_GET['mode']])
    include $pages[$_GET['mode']];
```

PS: The two `RewriteCond`'s make sure the url is not an existing file or folder (i.e. if you have a folder `images` then site.com/images will still go to that folder instead of `index.php?mode=images`.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in accepting this answer, I had to make sure it was up to scratch when I implemented it into my system, it works like a charm... so far! Thank you.